# HTMLで出力される文字色を、$_GET変数の値によって変更したい。

Tags: php, html, css

HTML+CSSおよびphpの初心者です。
$_GET変数で得た値が1であれば１の部分を赤色に、
2であれば2の部分を赤色に、3であれば3の部分を赤色に変更したいと思っております。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。

index.php

```html
<?php

$number = $_GET['id'];

print '<ul>';
print '<li class="light">1</li>';
print '<li>2</li>';
print '<li>3</li>';
print '</ul>';

?>
```

index.css

```
.light{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

[image: 結果]

Answer (score 1):

正直色々なやり方が考えられますが、愚直にやると次のような感じになるかと思います。

```
<?php
$number = $_GET['id'];

echo '<ul>';
for ($index = 1; $index <= 3; $index++) {
    echo '<li' , ($index == $number ? ' class="light">' : '>') , $index , '</li>'; 
}
echo '</ul>';
```

[三項演算子](http://php.net/manual/ja/language.operators.comparison.php) を使って、for文のループ番号 `$index` と `$number` を比較して一致したときのみ `class="light"` が出力されるようになっています。

Answer (score 0):

ページごとに振る舞いを変えたい箇所が複数ある場合は、
$_GET['id']で得た値をbodyのクラス名に出力すると便利です。

```
$bodyClass = 'page' . $_GET['id'];
```

としておいて、

```
<body class="<?php echo $bodyClass;?>">
```

とすれば、あとは条件に合わせたcssを静的に書いておけばバッチリです。

```
.page01 li:nth-child(1),
.page02 li:nth-child(2),
.page03 li:nth-child(3) {
    color: red;
}
```